# Substring in linux based on first occurrence

Tags: linux, string, unix

I have a raw unformatted Strings like below in a file.

```
"],"id":"1785695Jkc","vector":"profile","
"],"id":"jashj24231","vector":"profile","
"],"id":"3201298301","vector":"profile","
"],"id":"1123798749","vector":"profile","
```

I wanted to extract only the id values like below

```
1785695Jkc
```

I tried the below command

```
grep -o -P '(?<="],"id":").*(?=",")' myfile.txt >new.txt
```

but that takes the last occurance of the `","` like below

```
1785695Jkc","vector":"profile
```

but I would need to split on the first occurrence only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*to extract only the id values like* above which seem to be alphanumeric strings of length 10, use:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[[:alnum:]]{10}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
1785695Jkc
jashj24231
3201298301
1123798749
```

If the definition of *values like* is not correct, please be more specific on the requirement.

Btw, changing your `grep` a bit works also:

```
$ grep -o -P '(?<="],"id":")[^"]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/"],"id":"\(.*\)","vector.*/\1/' myfile.txt
```

that assumes that all lines will start with `"],"id":"` as your input shows.
Oh, and this is GNU sed btw, your sed may use extended regular expressions, in which case lose the quoting of the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract just the column you want using **cut**:

```
cut -f 2 -d , <filename> | cut -f 2 -d : | tr -d '"'
```

The first cut will take the id-value pair ("id": "jashj24231") and the second one extracts from that just the value ("jashj24231"). Finally **tr** removes the enclosing quotes.